# Devexpress Loading Issue

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I have designed a Devexpress winform with many Devexpress controls.
When it is loading,the form gets flickering.
Is there any solution,for loading of my form smoothly?

Comment: your form loading code please?

Comment: Which controls are you using? When are you binding the data? Does the whole form flicker or only certain controls? More info please...

Comment: I am using LookUpEDit,TextEdit,ComboBoxEdit,CheckedComboBoxEdit,RadioGroup,TabContainer

Comment: Maybe it works if you set the form.visible = false. Then show a statusform or sth. to show that sth. happen and if the controls finished loading you set the form.visible = true; and disable the statusform...

Comment: Maybe you should create a sample project and post it in the Devex support center? It's difficult to see what the problem could be :-/

Comment: Have you tried using the Property DoubleBuffered = true

Comment: Are these controls directly on the form or on a DataLayoutControl on the form?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a DataLayoutControl and set the methods "BeginUpdate" and "EndUpdate". This should help against the flickering.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old, but I answer it for someone else.

If the form is a general form(WinForm) rather than a form in Devexpress, it flashes when the entire form is redrawn if you used the Devexpress control in that form.

Make sure that the form you are using is XtraForm, and if it is not XtraForm, you must recreate it as XtraForm.

If you use XtraForm and it blinks Follow @Ronaldk6's comments.